# The process that must occur between the client and servers, Kerberos authentication

Tags: process, client, kerberos

Im trying to learn and understand Kerberos, i need to understand the process that must occur between the client and server — Windows and non-Windows platforms — to enable Kerberos authentication. looking for some help to explain the process better. 
thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of online resources. You will have to be more specific in your question. Here are some resources:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742516.aspx

http://www.markwilson.co.uk/blog/2005/06/kerberos-authentication-explained.htm

That Google suggests.